# Python pandas in if conditions: crash unknown

Tags: python, pandas, logical-operators

A peculiar issue, what is wrong in this code, when the if condition hits the code crashes.
This is the original code not in python but converting this to python code

```
efratio=noise!=0 ? signal/noise : 1
```

Background of the `stockdata` is nothing but dataframe value in pandas array. the array list has noise value when I compare this with `!=0` in Python I don't know why the program crashes.

Should I use numpy here as this dataframe has the list of data series?

```
    if (stockdata['noise']!= 0):
        stockdata['efratio']= (stockdata['signal']/stockdata['noise'])
    else :
        stockdata['efratio']= 1

    or
   stockdata['efratio']= (stockdata['signal']/stockdata['noise']) if (stockdata['noise']!= 0) else 1
```

**Edit1:**
The exception coming is

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
>   a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Comment: are you getting any error message?

Comment: No, after this line the call breaks and return to exception

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: Not much information but `stockdata['noise'] != 0` returns more than 1 value, so it will be always true...
Then, you are dividing by `stockdata['noise']` so probably you have a division by 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
if (stockdata['noise']!= 0):
        stockdata['efratio']= (stockdata['signal']/stockdata['noise'])
else :
    stockdata['efratio']= 1
```

to:

```
import numpy as np

stockdata['efratio'] = np.where(stockdata['noise'] != 0,
                                stockdata['signal'] / stockdata['noise'], 1)
```

This what happens:

> `where(condition, [x, y])`
>
> Return elements, either from `x` or `y`, depending on `condition`.

Comment: the same kind of error in this line of code as well coming ,anything to be modified   stockdata['kama'] = stockdata['kama'](-1) if stockdata['kama'][-1] !=0 else stockdata['close'] + stockdata['smooth']*(stockdata['close'] - stockdata['kama'](-1) if stockdata['kama'](-1) !=0 else stockdata['close'])

Comment: Does my solution fix your original error?

Comment: checked the solution provided by you it is working ! what shall be the fix for the issue given in comment.thank you

Comment: It is really difficult to read code in a comment. Best would be to ask a new question providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it is given in this stackoverflow post ,pleas check and support  /48838354/python-equivalent-function-logic-for-nonzero-value-calculation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

stockdata = pd.DataFrame({'noise': [10, 4, 0], 'signal': [1, 2, 3]})

logic = stockdata['noise'] != 0
stockdata['efratio'] = 1.0

stockdata['efratio'][logic] = stockdata['signal'][logic] / (stockdata['noise'][logic])
```